# DMS format to readable format

Tags: javascript, maps, latitude-longitude

I am using GPS devices in which Iam getting the location in DMS format.
The latitude and longitude which i am getting are:

- '3042.4016', 'N'
- '07646.9800', 'E'

I need it to get converted into readable format in javaScript.

Comment: These coords not in DMS format, but in ISO 6709.

Comment: So you can explain these numbers as ±DDDMMSS.S (degrees, minutes, seconds). Convering  these values to longitude, latitude is trivial, for example: https://www.latlong.net/degrees-minutes-seconds-to-decimal-degrees